# database for multi-user in vb6.0

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, adodb

I had completed an ERP system by using ms access 2003 and vb6.0 as my project, however, when i do testing for my project, i found a problem which is ms access 2003 only available for 1 pc user, i need it to be multi-user in different pc and able to do the read/write in same time, anyone can tell me how should i do to make my system become multi-user system? Attached with part of my coding for adodb and adodc, please help me how should i make this ERP system to be multi-user, appreciate for your help.

For Adodb:

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\simewood.mdb" & "; Persist Security Info=False;"
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open
strSQLmarketing = "select * from tblMarketing where Order_ID = '" & cboOrderID & "' and Model_ID = '" & cboModelID & "'"
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = strSQLmarketing
    .CommandType = adCmdText
End With
With rs
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open cmd
End With
```

For Adodc:

```
Adodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\simewood.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from tblLogin where status = 'enabled'"
```

Comment: Are they all on a local windows network?

Comment: not...is not in a local network, it will be access by multiple network from different area

Answer (score 0):

Access is not single-use, it is quite happy with multiple users (to a point - see below). However, every user has to have access to the .accdb file. So if the file is hidden in an unshared folder on one PC which can't be accessed from a second PC, that second PC won't be able to access it.

The number of concurrent users in Access is limited. The last time I used it for multiple users (Access 97) it started running out of steam at about 9 concurrent users. I don't know what more recent versions allow, but it will be less that 'grown up' databases like SQL Server, Oracle MySQL/MariaDB etc.

Comment: Actually the real limit is far closer to 255 users.  And even that depends on the usage scenario.  First you want to limit your applications to 1 connection per instance (a common mistake).  Then you can use a semi-connected model where only middleware connects/opens the database itself.  Finally in the cave man case with 1 connection per client instance you may want row-level locking, but even then lock contention can add up if there is a lot of updating.  But if 9 clients is slowing you down you are probably doing something *very* wrong.

Comment: how should i do the coding to make my .mdb file to activate for multi-user accessibility?? can you give me some sample? or you have others better recommendation?